# problemas con llaves al escribir hmtl desde javascript

Tags: javascript, html

tengo que crear desde javascript codigo hmtl

```
$("#materiasCheck").append(
"<div><input class='form-check-check' type='checkbox' name='skills[]' 
value='"+materiacheck.id+"' id='defaultCheck1' mx-auto: checked>
<label class='form-check-label' for='defaultCheck1'>"+materiacheck.materia+" 
/ {{App\\Materia_User::chkNCDocente(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)}}</label></div>");
```

pero recibo el error

```
syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting identifier (T_STRING)
```

tiene que ver directamente con {{ }}, que las necesito para llamar la funcion, alguien podria ayudarme a solucionar

Answer (score 0):

Pues yo diría que hay que escapar las comillas dobles que tengas por ahí para que no corten el string que estás añadiendo. Los saltos de línea tampoco ayudan mucho...

Nos falta un poco de código para saber qué es materiacheck.id y eso, pero seguro que con quitar los saltos de línea y escapar `"+materiacheck.materia+"` y volverlo `\"+materiacheck.materia+\"`, va a funcionar.

Y nada tienen que ver las pobres llaves que no le han hecho mal a nadie.